# re-render twice not same state when use fetch with useEffect in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am having the following problem.
This is my Code

```html
const [championData, setChampionData] = useState({})
  const championUrl = `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.5.1/data/en_US/champion/${champion}.json`
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(championUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setChampionData(data.data[champion])

      })
  }, []);

  console.log(championData)
```

when i console.log championData, ChampionData is re-render twice.
Fisrt time : It is undefined.
Second time : It is a object.
After i use it to .map() my code not run and console.log properties is undefined.
I mean when i pass data through other components and console.log it . It also re-render twice like that. And i can't take properties of objects. The web will crash if i do it.
I think it's because it is undefined in first time.

So how can i fix it, and re-render only once?

More infomation:

```html
return (
    <div className="championView">
      <Navbar />
      <ChampionViewOverview index={location.state.index} championData={championData} />
      <Abilities index={location.state.index} championData={championData} />
      <Skin index={location.state.index} championData={championData} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
```

when i take championData to ChampionViewOverView components and console.log(championData)
It re-render twice and first undefined , second is Object.

It make my web crash.
Thanks

I finally found a way to do it. that is i need to set the same properties as data from fetch.
This helps when passing to other components and using the map function for the internal properties not to be missing and crash.
Thanks for all supports.

Comment: The state will be set (to an empty object) when the component is loaded, and the state will change again when your fetch is returned and calls `setChampionData()`. There doesn't seem to be anything that needs fixing.

Comment: but when i pass data through other components and console.log it . It also re-render twice like that. And i can't take properties of objects. The web will crash if i do it

Comment: You will need to check whether your object is loaded before trying to use its properties, the standard way to do this is initialise the state to `null` until it is set to its proper value by the request.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I think I'll try setting it to null and use if else . hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Re-renders occur when there is a change in state. The state is set only when the component is loaded, and further state updating in `useEffect` takes place after the component has mounted, since the state is updated in `useEffect` hook, the component is re-rendered. Since you mentioned, mapping, I can safely assume that the `championData` is an array. Although you can't really prevent re-rendering, you can definitely fix the crashing issue. In your parent component or in the child component, you could use the optional chaining operator `?`, which maps or operates on a variable only when it has some value and is not `undefined`.

In your **ChampionViewOverview** component, you could use the optional chaining operator like below:

```
export default function ChampionViewOverview(props){
.
.
.
return(
<Fragment>
{props.championData?.map(obj=>return(//Return whatever)} //Optional chaining
</Fragment>
)
```

The above is just a sample and for demonstration purposes, shows how to use the optional chaining operator.

Comment: thanks. I will try it .

Answer (score 0):

I think that behaviour you are seeing is totally normal: you are trying to log a state value putting a `console.log` in component's body. Unfortunately you cannot do this in React because you don't know when component's body will be evaluated by React.

So first of all, I would move that log into an hook. So if you want to log the very last value of `championData` you could use `useEffect` in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(championData);
}, [championData])  //<-- this means, useEffect will be triggered every time championData changes
```

Second: you said that you are using `championData` somewhere in your code with a `map` BUT you initialized `championData` as an object:

```
const [championData, setChampionData] = useState({}) //<-- empty object
```

and `map` does not exists for JSON object. So I would change `championData` initialization in this way:

```
const [championData, setChampionData] = useState([]) //<-- void array instead of empty object
```

Comment: when i use useEffect to console the console prints too many times.  i think i will use if else to get the data a second time .

Comment: @NguyễnĐiệp this means that you are changing that value somewhere too many times. This is a red flag for you and you should check your code looking for the line that is changing this value all that times!

Comment: My main problem is that when I pass it to another component to use it, it uses the data twice. first from championData : [], and second time from championData : [{ ... }] . It will crash if i use fisrt data.

Comment: I will review my code. it's hard to see and edit it. Thanks for this answer

Comment: @NguyễnĐiệp is totally normal that component uses championData twice: because the value of championData comes from an async call. So first render championData = [] then answer comes from server and championData = [{...}]. Yes you should review your code looking for the line that is causing the crash. If you want, you can update your question showing us all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Because `useEffect` re-renders, removing the `StrictMode` isn't a good option. However, you can use the approach below to allow only one render:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false;

  async function startFetching() {
    const json = await fetchTodos(userId);
    if (!ignore) {
      setTodos(json);
    }
  }

  startFetching();

  return () => {
    ignore = true;
  };
}, [userId]);
```